# How to change the browser persistant blue select all highlight color?

Tags: css, xcode, highlight, frontend

I know how to change the highlighted text color but there is a persistent blue highlight I can't change on my sites.

here is a screenshot of my example https://i.stack.imgur.com/alm0I.png

To see an example visit the jsfiddle below and either command + a or ctrl + a to highlight all the text...

Is the blue here padding or margin being highlighted? 
Also, I noticed I can created more of it by placing [br] tags in the dom outside of [p] tags

Any thoughts on this ?

**EDIT:**

I created a fiddle to mess w/ this and better illustrate it:

```
::selection doesn't work
```

http://jsfiddle.net/designaroni/UTd3E/

Highlight the content that's run & you'll see the blue which is the offending culprit here.

anymore suggestions here?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I don't think it is currently possible to override highlighting in some elments, inputs and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to change how the browser hightlights your website. This issue is very browser specific, since different browsers hightlight in a different way. You can however set via CSS which parts of the website can or can't be highlighted via the user-select property.

Edit:
I thought you knew how to change the color of the selection, but now I see you meant the color of the text highlighted. The answer below might cover that ;)

Comment: Highlighting the background or the color of the text isn't the issue either, see this example I put together & highlight the text, the blue  in the offending color in this case.
 
http://jsfiddle.net/designaroni/UTd3E/

Answer (score 0):

You may customize the `::selection` pseudo-element. See the [documentation from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3aselection)

From the examples in the documentation, you may customize the selection colors as follows from the documentation:

```
/* draw any selected text yellow on red background */
#myelem::-moz-selection { color: gold;  background: red; }  /* For Firefox */
#myelem::selection      { color: gold;  background: red; }  /* Other ::selection-compatible browsers */
```

To make this apply to all selectable elements on the page:

```
*::-moz-selection { color: gold;  background: red; }  /* For Firefox */
*::selection      { color: gold;  background: red; }  /* Other ::selection-compatible browsers */
```

Note that this is a pseudo-element, and is not standardized, thus its behaviour is very implementation-defined.

Comment: I've done that but it doesn't target what I want to target...

See this example & highlight the text, the blue is the offending culprit I am talking about highlighting

http://jsfiddle.net/designaroni/UTd3E/